# css styling bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

:hover of the active question tab is really hard to read, on the meta there is a similar problem. I think we should change the colors

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch! I pushed a fix to our dev server. It will be live after our next production build(sometimes later today).